# Running Web Server does not work in Xamarin.iOS in (IOS-17)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview, xamarin.ios, ios17

I am facing an issue while running a web server within my Xamarin iOS application using the EmbedIO library. The web server serves static files, and it works perfectly on older iOS versions and in the iOS 17 simulator. However, when the code runs on an actual iOS 17 device (iPad 6th gen, running iPadOS 17.0.2), in web view it shows nothing.

I have set up a web server in my Xamarin iOS app using the EmbedIO library with the following code:

```
staticFilesWebServer = new WebServer(o => o
                        .WithUrlPrefix("http://localhost:8080")
                        .WithMode(HttpListenerMode.EmbedIO))
                    .WithLocalSessionManager()
                    .WithStaticFolder("/", location, true, m => m
                        .WithContentCaching(true)
                    );
                staticFilesWebServer.RunAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

In my XAML, I use a WebView to access the web server:

```
        <WebView
            x:Name="WebView"
             Grid.Row="1"
         HorizontalOptions="Fill"
         VerticalOptions="Fill" 
             source="http://localhost:8080"
            />
```

***Please see the attached screenshot [image 1] On the actual device web view with the running webserver is blank
[image 2] working fine on simulator***
[image: On actual device]

[image: On simulator]

Point me a direction on how to resolve this, currently, there is no error application console; it's just showing the white screen

Comment: Have you tried HTTPS instead of http? You might have to implement something between NSAllowsArbitraryLoads & NSAppTransportSecurity in your plist if you want to use http @RaGibNoor

Comment: key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
 </dict>
already allowed ,
same code is working in ios 16 facing this issue after ios 17 release

Comment: Update :  Using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost resolved my issue for IOS 17